# Host Google sign in client sources locally

Tags: google-signin

We are in the process of implementing [Sign In With Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button) functionality on our website. In the tutorial code snippet, external script is loaded from Google server:

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

Is it possible to host this library locally? Where can I find all the files that I need to download?

**EDIT:**

I tried saving the JavaScript file content locally. However, it still tries to load the styles from the external URL (https://accounts.google.com/gsi/style). I guess I could modify the source of JavaScript source code so that it loads this CSS from my server, but it seems like an ugly solution to me. Is there any other way besides modifying their source code?

Comment: Well, the script source is just there in your code. Have you tried opening that URL, saving the contents to a file and referencing that in your script tag?

Comment: @juzraai Please see updated question. I tried saving the file locally, but it still tries to load some CSS from Google's server. I would like to store ALL the files that Google-Sign-In library needs locally.